# How can I create aar file using build.gradle

Tags: android

I created a project as a library and I wrote a class in that. Now I want to have an `aar` file from that using `build.gradle`.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }
}
```

What changes are needed in the above code?

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure that your `<modulename>/build.gradle` contains the right plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

Then you can create with

```
gradlew aR
```

your release aar file. Which will land in `<modulename>\build\outputs\aar` directory with the name `modulename-release.aar`.

---

The more tricky part is to include that aar file to your project (if you don't use maven or jcenter).

You need to put this lines to your `<projectroot>/build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        flatDir { dirs('aars') }
    }
}
```

When you put your aar files in `<modulename>/aars`, then you can include your aar file in your desired module like this:

```
compile(name:'<your-aar-file-name>', ext:'aar')
```